# show only latest rows from a database with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, chat

I've been trying to retrieve new rows from a databse with ajax. like the sort of thing that happens on facebook chat. What I've been doing is I get the last ten rows from the database with ajax every two seconds and try to show the ones the user hasn't seen. I have two columns, id and name. I created an onordered list and set each li elements id to the id from the database. each li is for a row. then I try to get the id of the last li element and check if the id from the database is greater, if it is then append a new li containing the id and name. but for some reason, it just appends the whole 10 rows every two seconds. what have I done wrong?
this is the code I'm using.

```
<ol id="output"><li id="1">test</li></ol>

<script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">



function reloadw() 
{


 $.ajax({                                      
  url: 'api.php',                  
  data: "",        
  dataType: 'json',                     
  success: function(rows)         
  {
  for (var i in rows)
{   
var row = rows[i]; 
  var lastId = $('ol#output li').attr('id');
   var id = row[0];
  var vname = row[1];



  if(id > lastId){
  $('#output').append("<li id="+id+"><b>id: </b>"+id+"<b> name: </b>"+vname+"</li>"); 
  }}
  }

});
 }  setInterval(reloadw,2000);
```

this is what I use in retrieving data from the db

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tableName ORDER BY id");            
$data = array();
for($i=0;$i<=9;$i++){
 $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$data[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode( $data );
```

Comment: have you not considered simply running the sql query from the last id?

Comment: why don't u use `LIMIT` in your query ? The way you are doing now will fetch all records from the database on each ajax call which is a performance issue..

Comment: I'm trying to write a chat app so returning the last row of a specific number of rows won't do

Answer (score 1):

If you take out issue where you are fetching the data, another issue you have is in your javascript code.

Change

```
var lastId = $('ol#output li').attr('id'); //will always fetch the first li's id
```

to

```
var lastId =  $('ol#output li:last').attr('id');
```

With the `lastId` selection code that you have, it will always fetch only the id of the first one and your comparison `id > lastId` will always be true except for the first element's id. So you end up appending even if that record has been already added before.

*But ideally you should do this logic at the server to get only the data to be presented.*

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort last result from database this is very simple, you can try this code in your sql: `$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tableName ORDER BY id DESC");`

Answer (score 0):

```
var lastId = $('ol#output li').attr('id');
```

That line will always lookup the *first* element in the list, whereas you probably are looking for the last. Try replacing the line with:

```
var lastId = $('ol#output li').last().attr('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write your JavaScript code like this.

```
    <script>

        var seen = new Array();
        function reloadw(){


         $.ajax({                                      
          url: 'api.php',                  
          data: "",        
          dataType: 'json',                     
          success: function(rows){

          rows.forEach(function(row){


               if(seen.indexOf(row.id) == -1){

                         $('#output').append("<li id="+row.id+"><b>id: </b>"+row.id+"<b> name: </b>"+row.name+"</li>"); 

                          seen.push(row.id);

                      }

});

         }  setInterval(reloadw,2000);
    </script>
```

Comment: I tried your code and it returned 'id: undefined name: undefined'

Comment: rows needs to be an array of objects with an id and name field. The server side code needs to make the object like that before making a JSON string. You may need to use JSON.parse(rows).forEach(function(row){ // do stuff    }); if the ajax request doesn't automatically convert it to a JSON object.